# Como configurar UTF-8 no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, utf-8

Este erro apareceu no **Android Studio**. Será que há alguma configuração para arrumar?

> Error:(85, 69) error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode resolver esse problema de duas maneiras:

1. converter o arquivo para utf-8
2. colocar o tipo correto de encoding no seu build.gradle script.

Para converter o arquivo, clique no menu, abaixo a direita na sua IDE. Selecione o tipo correto de encoding (tipo utilizado autalmente), em seguida pressione "reload", selecione UTF-8 e pressione converter.

Para a segunda solução, coloque o tipo correto de encoding, no seu build.gradle, da seguinte maneira:

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251' // coloque seu encoding atual aqui
    ...
```

Esse [blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/) é bem interessante também. Recomendo a leitura.

Comment: Caso a resposta esteja correta, por favor, faça a marcação necessária :).